# Microsoft.Band SDK is not found on nuget? Even when looking with the pre-release options?

Tags: sdk, microsoft-band

As the title mentions, the sdk for the band I can't seem to get it to download.  Is the build server not up or did the build changed and not deploy right?

Thanks!
Alessandro

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what you've tried, on what platform, and with what version(s); I have no problems finding and applying the latest Band SDK NuGet package to a new Windows (8.1) project on Visual Studio 2015 (RTM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Band SDK is now available in the Nuget Store you can easily
install it with the Nuget Managers **Package Manager Console** line:

> Install-Package Microsoft.Band

or you install it with:

Right Click on your project => "Manage NuGet Packages" => Search "Band"

And then you can Install this:

[image]

Or if you want to use it with Xamarin you can install one of these:

[image]

You can see here the actual NuGet Versions:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Band/